# Is there a list of luxury resources?

Tags: civilization-5

In civilization 5 is there a way to see a list of all the resources your civ. has? I know I can see the different kinds in the happiness menu and the count on the trade screen. I just want a list of all the resources without taunting another civ. by contacting them to see if I have 3 spices and 2 whales.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I highly recommend the "Luxury Resource Display" mod. It's one of the higher-ranked mods at the moment, for good reason - it makes you permanently just a mouse-hover away from seeing a detailed list of how many luxury resources you currently have of each kind, including how many are traded.

Just search for it in the in-game mod hub, it's easily found, but it seems to also be downloadable from [here](http://www.weplayciv.com/forums/downloads.php?do=file&id=263) (I recommend the in-game method, though).

[image: screenshot of mod in action]

Comment: This overview seems to be built-in to the game now. Also you can mouse over your happiness icon to see a less-detailed overview of *which* resources you have. (It doesn't tell you in what amounts.)

Answer (score 9):

The latest patch added a "Resources and Happiness" tab to the Economic Overview screen.  I can't get a screenshot at the moment, but I think it shows similar information to the mod above.

Now that I'm home and can check it out, it shows you all of the above and a whole lot more.  Individual city contributions to unhappiness and happiness, all the resources that are available and what you're doing with them, etc.