# List of gems only obtainable by drops

Tags: path-of-exile

Was just wondering if anyone ever came across a compiled list of gems that are only obtainable through drops? I.E. you can't get them as quest rewards.

These are, by their nature, more rare than their quest reward counterparts.  Would be nice to have a list like this to prevent getting scammed while bartering.

Thanks!

Comment: something like this, but omitting the ones obtainable through quests. http://blackrabbit2999.blogspot.com/2012/07/path-of-exile-quest-gem-reward-list.html

Comment: Arqade's not really good for lists.  I mean, there's 49 support gems, and 81 skill gems.  That list would be reduced by available quest rewards, but I dunno if it's even reasonable at that point.

Comment: [here's one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66116/what-are-the-special-abilities-the-unique-champion-monsters-can-have), [another](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/list-of-starcraft-ii-detectors), [another](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/is-there-a-list-of-luxury-resources),        [another](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/44438/list-of-spirits-drinks-in-bastion).....  Excuse me, but if you aren't here to answer the question, can you just disregard it and move along? Thanks

Comment: Notice the small limits on those; we do allow list questions, so long as it's not TOO great a list.  I'm trying to decide if this is within the reasonable area.  It could very well be, I don't know for sure right now.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc No need to be snippy.  [Let's all be friends](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDkvgva_u58)

Comment: The maximum bound of the list is 130, but it's most likely less than that because it's only a subset. List feasibility is better judged by usefulness in being a list, not by the end-goal size of the list - usually giant sized lists aren't of very useful things or aren't the kind of stuff that warrants a list to be effective. But this seems to have a pretty clear and usable focus.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc [This is a good read](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/list-questions-for-the-old-republic-mmos-cw-closure-other/3722#3722) if you're curious about the position on lists. I don't know enough about PoE to know whether this question meets my standard (i.e. is the answer short enough that I'd be willing to write it up), but there's a reason people are resistant to the l-word.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc: Anyone with >3k reputation is able to vote to cast questions, not just mods, and a questions requires 5 such votes to be closed. The reason we have the ability to close questions is that some questions just don't work on our site, for whatever reason. List questions are type of question which sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't. fbueckert was just expressing his concern that he wasn't sure if this was the type of list question which worked on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Path of Exile wiki](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/List_of_drop-only_gems), there are only a few gems that are not quest rewards:

- Added Chaos Damage (can randomly be sold by Catarina)
- Detonate Mines
- Empower (can randomly be sold by Haku)
- Enhance (can randomly be sold by Tora)
- Enlighten (can randomly be sold by Catarina)
- Portal

There are also 2 skills that are only obtainable by vendor recipes

- Mirror arrow: Blink Arrow plus an Orb of Alteration.
- Block Chance Reduction: Puncture plus any dexterity based shield with 20% quality.

Comment: GMP, chain, conc effect... perfect!  This is what I was looking for.  This is tremendously valuable to newer PoE players, especially if they want to barter for gems.  I see people buying no-quality quest reward gems for alchs, fusings and even GCPs sometimes and I facepalm ..

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc Most of that is due to there not being a single global resource to define value; it's really hard to tell sometimes if what you're offering is even equal.  And people sometimes get offended if what you've offered is well below the value of the item.

Comment: But a quest reward gem will never be worth a GCP, becuase you can just re-roll infinitely and get those gems over and over.  I saw someone give a GCP for an LMP, which is overpaid because there's theoretically a never-ending supply of LMPs.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc It depends on how common GCPs become; if they become too common, then, yes, skill gems might be worth one.  That's the problem with having multiple items making up your economy; it's a really fine balancing act.

Comment: @MarcoLeblanc `But a quest reward gem will never be worth a GCP, becuase you can just re-roll infinitely and get those gems over and over.` You do realize that some of those quest gems are obtained from high level quests, some can only be obtained from quests in cruel and some only from quests in merciless (other then drops). So paying a good amount of orbs is sometimes just easier then to grind that far with certain character just to get that gem you want. Of course while some quest reward gems are valuable because of that fact, none of them should be worth a gcp.

Comment: Do note that Phase Run gem has been removed from the game once the game reached Open Beta. At the moment only some monsters have the phase run ability and it's not available to players anymore.

Comment: New drop-only gems include "Enlighten", "Enhance" and "Empower". Could you add those to the list? :)